# Why React changes my checked props?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to write a TODO List with React, but when I change a TodoItem's `check` attribute, **I got an opposite result.** `defaultChecked` is also useless.

```
      var Todo = React.createClass({
      getInitialState(){
        return{i:0,data:[],allCompleted:false};
      },
      handleKeyPress(e){
        if(e.key === 'Enter' && e.currentTarget.value != ''){
          localStorage.setItem(uuid(e.currentTarget.value),JSON.stringify({uuid:uuid(e.currentTarget.value),checked:false,todoContent:e.currentTarget.value}));
          this.state.data.push({uuid:uuid(e.currentTarget.value),checked:false,todoContent:e.currentTarget.value});
          this.setState({i: ++(this.state.i),data:this.state.data},
            ()=>{e.target.value = ''});

        }
      },
      /*
       *↓Here I made every item.checked = true when I click the all-completed checkbox;
       */
      handleAllComplete(e){
        if(!this.state.allCompleted){
          this.state.allCompleted = true;
          this.state.data.map((item)=>{item.checked?true:item.checked = !item.checked});
          return this.setState({data:this.state.data});
        }
        this.state.allCompleted = false;
        this.state.data.map((item)=>{item.checked = false});
        return this.setState({data:this.state.data});

      },
      handleOneComplete(todoUuid){
      console.log('one completed');    
        this.state.data.map((item)=>{item.uuid==todoUuid?(item.checked = !item.checked):undefined;});
        this.setState({data:this.state.data});
      },
      componentWillMount(){
        let data = [];
        for(var i in localStorage){
          if(localStorage.hasOwnProperty(i)){
            data.push(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(i)));
          }
        }
        this.setState({i:i,data:data});
      },
      render(){
        console.log(this.state.data);
        return <div>
          <AddTodoItem handleKeyPress={this.handleKeyPress} handleAllComplete={this.handleAllComplete}/>
          <TodoItemContainer data={this.state.data} handleOneComplete={this.handleOneComplete}/>
          <TodoToolBar />
        </div>
      }
    });

      var TodoItemContainer = React.createClass({
      render(){
        var todoItems = [];
        for(let i of this.props.data){

          todoItems.push(<TodoItem key={i.uuid} uuid={i.uuid} checked={i.checked} content={i.todoContent} style={i.checked?{color:'red'}:undefined} handleOneComplete={this.props.handleOneComplete}/>);
          console.log(i.checked,'in container');
          /*
           *↑Here's I got the check attribute is true and it meets my expectations;
           */
        }
        if(todoItems.toString() == ''){
          return <div></div>;
        }

        return <div>{todoItems}</div>;

      }
    })

      var TodoItem = React.createClass({
      getInitialState(){
        return ({checked:this.props.checked,todoContent:this.props.content});
      },
      componentWillReceiveProps(){
      /*
       *but Here, i got checked = false and that's my question;
       */
        console.log(this.props.checked,'will receive');
        this.setState({checked:this.props.checked,todoContent:this.props.content});
      },
      render(){
        console.log(this.state.checked,'render item');
        return <div>
          <input type="checkbox" defaultChecked={this.state.checked} onChange={this.props.handleOneComplete.bind(null,this.props.uuid)}/>
          <lable style={this.props.style}>{this.state.todoContent}</lable>
          <button>delete</button>
        </div>
      },
    });
```

Simplely speaking, I set every `TodoItem checked = true`,but within `TodoItem` I got `this.props.checked` is `false`

https://jsfiddle.net/20xads1n/1/

Comment: Can you upload code to jsfiddle, with `react-dom`, `render` your component to dom(then, people here can further more look)? Checked your code, also confused.

Comment: @DavidGuan  thanks for your advice and I uploaded it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is fixed version of your example
https://jsfiddle.net/7s99f2aj/.
There were 2 problems:

1) you missed `nextProps` argument in `componentWillReceiveProps`method  (see https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html#updating-componentwillreceiveprops)
2) I changed `defaultChecked` to `checked` in your `TodoItem` component

Also I'd like to recommend you to use `setState` everywhere when you change your state (i.e. `this.setState({allCompleted: true})` instead of `this.state.allCompleted = true;`) and not mutate state directly within `map` functions like this: `this.state.data.map((item)=>{item.checked?true:item.checked = !item.checked});`. Instead, consider to create completely new `data` object and change you state using `setState`.